# Collection transform stops "created" timestamp

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to implement created/updated timestamps as in the [UMFAQ](https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#how-can-i-alter-every-document-before-it-is-added-to-the-database). I can get the "created" timestamp working, but when I add in a transform to the collection my timestamp stops working.

```
Post = function (document) {
    _.extend(this, document);
}

Post.prototype = {
    constructor: Post,

    formatDate: function () {
        return this.due.toDateString();
    }

}

Posts = new Meteor.Collection("post", {
    transform: function (document) {
        return new Post(document);
    }   
});

Posts.deny({
    insert: function (userId, doc) {
        doc.created = new Date(); // timestamp
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dont transform on the server end:

```
if(Meteor.isClient) {
    Posts = new Meteor.Collection("post", {
        transform: function (document) {
        return new Post(document);
    }
}

if(Meteor.isServer) {
    Posts = new Meteor.Collection("post");
}
```